# $A,B\in L(X)$ is positive semidefinition hermitian operators and $A^2=B^2$, then $A=B.$

Tags: functional-analysis

Please help demonstrate that applies: **If $A,B\in L(X)$ is positive semidefinition hermitian operators and $A^2=B^2$, then $A=B.$**

where $X$ is Hilbert space (real or complex), and $L(X$) algebra of bounded operators of $X$ ON $X$.

Operator $A\in L_H(X)$ is positive semidefiniton, write $A\geq 0$, if $(Ax\vert x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in X.$

where $L_H(X)$ is set of all hermitian operators on $L(X).$

Thanks for your help and your attention. Thanky very much. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: You'll either need the spectral theorem, or a result that guarantees the existence of a positive square root $C$ of $A^{2}=B^{2}$ that commutes with every operator which commutes with $A^{2}=B^{2}$.

Comment: If you could please help me, to solve this example

Comment: Do you know either of those two results that I mentioned?

Comment: I know the spactral theorem, but I didnt now how to prove this example, please if you can prove it then do the above example,

Comment: I have here the example verification but did not clear, so the bed sheets in this site example, the belief that there are many colleagues who are willing to help, giving solutions which can be understandable for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one result other than the spectral theorem that you'll need; I'll assume you've seen a proof; otherwise, let me know. Note: I rarely deal with real spaces, but I don't think anything below is specific to complex spaces.

> **Lemma** Let $E$ be a positive semidefinite selfadjoint operator on a Hilbert space $X$. Then $(Ex,x)=0$ iff $Ex=0$.

Okay, so I'll assume the spectral theorem and the above lemma. The operator $C=A^{2}$ is positive semidefinite. So you can use the functional calculus of the spectral theorem to find a positive semidefinite $\sqrt{C}\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ such that $\sqrt{C}^{2} = C$, and such that $\sqrt{C}$ commutes with every bounded operator which commutes with $C$. Notice that $A$ commutes with $C$. Therefore $A\sqrt{C}=\sqrt{C}A$. (If you know something about MASA (Maximal Abelian Selfadjoint Algebras) then you could finish fairly easily. I won't assume that.)

Now you can factor because $\sqrt{C}$ and $A$ commute:
$$
       (\sqrt{C}-A)(\sqrt{C}+A)=C-A^{2}=0.
$$
That means $\sqrt{C}-A=0$ on the closure $\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{C}+A)^{c}$ of the range $\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{C}+A)$. The orthogonal complement of $\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{C}+A)$ is $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{C}+A)$. So the proof that $\sqrt{C}=A$ is finished by showing that $\sqrt{C}$ and $A$ are $0$ on $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{C}+A)$, which gives $\sqrt{C}-A=0$ on $X=\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{C}+A)^{c}\oplus\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{C}+A)^{\perp}$.

So assume that $(\sqrt{C}+A)x=0$. Then
$$
     0 \le (\sqrt{C}x,x) \le ((\sqrt{C}+A)x,x) = 0 \implies (\sqrt{C}x,x)=0,\\
     0 \le (Ax,x) \le ((\sqrt{C}+A)x,x) = 0 \implies (Ax,x)=0.
$$
By the lemma, $\sqrt{C}x=0$ and $Ax=0$, which finishes the proof that $A=\sqrt{C}$. Similarly $B=\sqrt{C}$.